# Save UIPickerView selection to NSUserDefaults swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uipickerview

I am trying to save the user's selection from UIPickerView to NSUserDefaults. I have found answers in obj-c but not swift. Here is my UIPickerView code:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        race = pickerData[row]
    }
```

And when you press a save button, it is supposed to save what is selected to NSUserDefaults. Here is my saving code:

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
        var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(race, forKey: "race")
    }
```

When I try to display the text on a label, it shows up blank:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.raceLabel.text = defaults.objectForKey("race") as? String
```

Let me know if my question needs any clarification, thanks.

Comment: Where is called save:?

Comment: it's in the same viewcontroller class as the pickerview @Larme

Comment: And where are you retrieving the value? Where do you try to display the text on a label?

Comment: okay i edited it to show where i tried to show it @Larme

Comment: What's the value of `race` when you save it?

Comment: shouldn't it be `pickerdata[row]` ? @Larme

Comment: It should be, but for example, is `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` called before saving `race`?

Comment: i don't know...all of my pickerview code has been edited to show on the question @Larme

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as specified below and it will work

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent     component: Int) {
    race = row   
}
```

Every time you select a row, this function is called and the argument of the parameter `row` represents the row that was selected in your UIPickerView.

If you assign  `pickerData[row]` value to `race`, you are assigning a value from your pickerData array at the index number represented by the row selected in your UIPickerView Object.